# NSMutableArray empty after created in init (with code)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *authorMutableArray;

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.authorMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First Row", @"Second Row", nil];

        for (NSString *string in authorMutableArray) {
            NSLog(@"String: %@", string);
        }

        NSLog(@"Init in Add Model with Author count:%i", [authorMutableArray count]);


    }
}
```

An example of accessing the property. The NSLog always shows the count as 0.

```
    - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) { 
        if (indexPath.row == [self.addModel.authorMutableArray count] - 1 ) {
            NSLog(@"count of %i", [self.addModel.authorMutableArray count]);
            return  UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        }

        else {
            return  UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

        }
    }

    else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

The array I'm creating in init is not keeping its values past this method. Any reason why? The for loop will show both objects in the array. If I try to ask this after the init method is called, the array is empty.

Updated: Thank you everyone for your time and eyes. I had forgotten to return self in the init method.

Comment: How do you declare the authormutablearray property

Comment: It's regular synthesized property.

Comment: @WDyson What Warren means is, what specifiers are you using? `strong`, `weak`, `assign`? Also, how are you accessing the array afterwards? Can you show us the code for that?

Comment: I'll update the OP, it's strong.

Comment: In your `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method, check to see if `addModel` is not nil, too.

Comment: The addModel is not nil. Just checked. It has other NSString properties, and I can access those just fine.

Comment: `indexPath.row == [self.addModel.authorMutableArray count] > 1` doesn't make much sense... is it a typo? Perhaps `- 1`?

Comment: Yes, that's typo, thanks. The wonder of fresh eyes!

Comment: Is the init method being called? For example, if you are dealing with a Document based app, a new document calls `initWithType:error:` so that the code you put in your `init` method is never executed.

Comment: see my answer, and please if it is not a technical issue dont tag with Xcode

Comment: I am calling init when I create addModel, nothing else.

Comment: I think pre found the problem, see his answer below!

Comment: The `NSLog` in `if (indexPath.row == [self.addModel.authorMutableArray count] - 1 )` cannot log `0` because that would mean that the if statement would be `if (indexPath.row == -1)`, which is never `true`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't the init method return self ?

Comment: Yes, it did. I have 4 NSString properties I was creating in the same init method, I just excluded them for this example. They all worked fine. Why is it the array was the only one not to keep its data?

Answer (score 0):

In your class' interface file(.h file) declare like this:

```
@interface Your_Class_Name : UIViewController {
   NSMutableArray *authorMutableArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *authorMutableArray;
//i dont know why you prefered strong, chose retain and try again please
```

Comment: `strong` is the equivalent to `retain` under ARC. They have equivalent semantics in their respective memory management systems. It's also unecessary to declare the ivar separately; it's created by `@synthesize`.

Comment: @lulius, which would you use for the array, strong or retain?

Comment: `copy`, actually, for a class that has a mutable counterpart, but the choice between `strong` and `retain` simply depends on whether you're using ARC or not.

Comment: Strong for ARC, retain otherwise? And what do you mean by mutable counterpart? I just want to make sure I completely understand.

Comment: @WDy Yes, `strong` under ARC. Mutable counterpart meaning `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`, `NSString`/`NSMutableString`, `NSIndexSet`/`NSMutableIndexSet`, and so on. If a mutable instance is passed in to your setter, it can be changed by the original owner unless you take a copy, which may have surprising results. There are SO questions around that go into more depth about that.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I thought that was what you were talking about. But I'm not familiar with the inner workings of ARC, thought you might be referring to something more in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

We aren't dealing with C++ or Java here, the `-init` method of an object `MUST` return a value.

This quirk actually allows for some pretty interesting stuff, e.x. the following:

```
-(id) init {
    NSLog(@"Creating new instance of singleton object...");

    #if __has_feature(objc-arc)
    self = singleton_instance;
    #else
    [self release];
    self = [singleton_instance retain];
    #endif   

    return self;
}
```

It also allows for class 'posing' of a sort, allowing you to track exactly when an object of a particular class is initialized (that is too deep of a topic for this answer).